# What does this kMSDataBaseType error mean in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, linker

I am trying to copy all the files from one project to a new project which run on .net standard 2.0 but encountered an error for xamarin.ios

> Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _kMSDataBaseDataType. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

It must be something to do with linking but not sure how what it refer to

Comment: Does your old project run on share project?

Comment: You only copy the file that you created.And ignore some native renference.Check the renference of your old  project and add them in your new project.

Comment: i think i get rid of the error. A question: If i have a .net standard 2.0 library called 'Moment' project with iOS 'Moment.iOS' project. And want to use it on other projects. Do i need only to copy the dll of 'Moment.dll' and 'Moment.iOS.dll'? Do i need to copy other libraries that Moment's project uses e.g. FFImageLoading

Comment: You can have a try.I think it is necessary.